# HTML responsive on all devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tried various thing but I simply cannot get my webpage to autoscale when you drag a window or when you use your phone, I have created the script.js and the css.

here is the code, could you please tell me or send me the code for the css and js?

Thanks and sorry

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="sr-lang-en" lang="en"
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Rivalo Willkommensbonus </title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
</head>
<div id="content">
  <body class="theme">
    <div id="themeBackground" style="background: url(bg.jpg);padding-top:130px;padding-left:00px;padding-bottom:130px;">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
          <center>
            <div id="content" class="left">
              <div id="main_wide">
                <div class="cms_richtext">
                  <div class="box">
                    <a href="https://www.rivalo.com/de/wettkonto-anmelden/">
                      <div style="background:url(header_de_main-min.jpg) top center no-repeat;width:1011px;height:494px;"></div>
                    </a>
                    <div style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:40px;width:950px;">
                      <a href="https://www.rivalo.com/de/wettkonto-anmelden/">
                        <style scope="" type="text/css">
                          div.box1 {
                          opacity: 0.9;
                          filter: alpha(opacity=90); /* For IE8 and earlier */
                          }
                          div.box1:hover {
                          opacity: 1.0;
                          filter: alpha(opacity=100); /* For IE8 and earlier */
                          -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1); 
                          -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1); 
                          box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(255,255,255,1);
                          }                 
                        </style>
                      </a>
                      <a href="https://www.rivalo.com/de/casino-spielen/">
                        <div class="box1" style="width:219px;height:173px;float:left;background:url(header_de_1-min.jpg) top center no-repeat;margin-right:9px">&nbsp;</div>
                      </a>
                      <a href="https://www.rivalo.com/de/live-wetten/">
                        <div class="box1" style="width:220px;height:173px;float:left;background:url(header_de_2-min.jpg) top center no-repeat;margin-right:9px;margin-left:9px">&nbsp;</div>
                      </a>
                      <a href="https://www.rivalo.com/de/sportwetten-bonus/">
                        <div class="box1" style="width:220px;height:173px;float:left;background:url(header_de_3-min.jpg) top center no-repeat;margin-right:9px;margin-left:9px">&nbsp;</div>
                      </a>
                      <a href="https://www.rivalo.com/de/wettkonto-anmelden/">
                        <div class="box1"style="width:220px;height:173px;float:left;background:url(header_de_4-min.jpg) top center no-repeat;margin-right:9px;margin-left:9px">&nbsp;</div>
                      </a>
                      <div style="clear:both">&nbsp;</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
  TableHeight();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using absolute CSS units isn't going to help.

Comment: You're going to want to use percentages rather than pixels like Scott mentioned. Add max-width to the div directly within the box div and change the width of the box 1's to width: calc(25% - 18px) -- that way they'll each be 25% of the box while still accounting for the margin.

Comment: Parts of your HTML is obsolete (the center element) and is missing required components (a doctype). SO is here to help with what you wrote but asking us to supply markup is not allowed.

Comment: A couple of general thoughts... Do you have a particular reason to still support IE8? Even IE9 has been around for 6 years. Also, reconsider the unnecessary "divitis" (http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/faqs/what-is-divitis/) that your HTML structure uses. Also, comply with modern standards. `<center>` is no longer standard. `box-shadow` and `opacity` are standard. There is no need to vendor prefix them. Your `style` element is using the `scope` attribute, but the attribute is `scoped` and is non-standard.

Comment: is there a simple js or css I can just simply add?

Comment: @Julian look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479304/3944910

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the quotes around "viewport" in the following line in your code:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

should be

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"; initial-scale="1.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use percentage instead of pixel when giving a value to a width or a hight

Answer (score -1):

**update:**

there is a jquery plugin for zoom in/out all of elements, download it from [here](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/).

here is an example:

```
<div id="element">Click me to zoom</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#element").click(function(evt) {
    $(this).zoomTo({targetsize:2, duration:600});
    evt.stopPropagation();
 });
});
```

look at [this demo](http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/examples/isometric/index.html) of zoomooz.js.

In css3 ,you can use @media to detecting  different width of screen. Look at this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: While I agree with you, if you read the comments, you will see that the OP clearly stated (way before your posted your answer) that he does not (for some reason) want to use media queries.